# ValueError: Dimensions must be equal keras tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a model of this structure:

```
    model = models.Sequential() 
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))) 
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3),strides=(2,2), padding="same", dilation_rate=(1,1), activation='relu')) 
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding="same"))  
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3),padding="same", activation='relu')) 
    model.add(layers.Flatten()) 
    model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))  
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

All of the above seems to work, when trying to train using

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

I get the following error:Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "D:\phthon\py\landuse\main.py", line 83, in <module>
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
  File "D:\anaconda\envs\landuse\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filewqf6pnrl.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "D:\anaconda\envs\landuse\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\landuse\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\landuse\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\landuse\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 998, in train_step
        return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\landuse\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1092, in compute_metrics
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\landuse\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 605, in update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\landuse\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 77, in decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\landuse\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\base_metric.py", line 143, in update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\landuse\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\base_metric.py", line 700, in update_state  **
        matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\landuse\lib\site-packages\keras\metrics\metrics.py", line 3669, in sparse_categorical_accuracy
        matches = metrics_utils.sparse_categorical_matches(y_true, y_pred)
    File "D:\anaconda\envs\landuse\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 970, in sparse_categorical_matches
        matches = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), backend.floatx())

    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 14059 and 1757 for '{{node Equal}} = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, incompatible_shape_error=true](Squeeze, Cast_1)' with input shapes: [?,14059,1], [?,1757,1].
```

x_train.shape is (8943, 14059, 7, 1)
y_train.shape is (8943, 14059, 1, 1)

model.summary()
Model: "sequential"

---

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 14057, 5, 32)      320       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 7028, 2, 32)      0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 3514, 1, 64)       18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 1757, 1, 64)      0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 1757, 1, 128)      73856     
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 1757, 1, 256)      33024     
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1757, 1, 6)        1542      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 127,238
Trainable params: 127,238
Non-trainable params: 0
```

how can i change it to run this model ,is my data too big?

Comment: Flatten layer is missing in the summary, you may be executing wrong model code for it.